# How to label dates in a new column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I want to label my dataframe, in Python, such as in the example below:

```
Index                               Activity
2020-01-27 00:08:01.882000+00:00    Sleep
2020-01-27 00:16:33.848000+00:00    Sleep
2020-01-27 00:25:06.131000+00:00    Sleep
2020-01-27 00:33:59.917000+00:00    Sleep 
2020-01-27 00:42:31.884000+00:00    Sleep 
.
.
.
2020-01-27 13:04:59.940000+00:00    Work
2020-01-27 13:13:31.907000+00:00    Work
2020-01-27 13:22:03.873000+00:00    Work
2020-01-27 13:30:02.953000+00:00    Work
2020-01-27 13:38:34.919000+00:00    Work
.
.
.
```

Considering that I have the index which consists in a number of dates as in the example above, the column 'Activity' is the new one that I want to create based on those dates.

For *example*, from the date '2020-01-27 00:04:59.940000+00:00'I am sleeping until '2020-01-27 07:01:43.940000+00:00', and from '2020-01-27 08:30:01.920000+00:00'I am working until '2020-01-27 18:15:10.940000+00:00', and the activities can go further...

I know how to create a new column and how to assign the label (the activity word - sleep, work, etc..) but I don't know how to select the specific dates within that activity is performed. (like a while date < ... or something). I hope that you understand what I am referring to. If you don't then I will try to update my post.

NOTE: ** My dates should not be changed and they are the index to my dataframe. **

I searched this subject but I have not found anything that could help me. I would highly appreciate if you could help me!

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: do you mean `df[df['Acivitiy'].eq('Sleep')]?` in any case thanks for adding input, can you add an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your index is of the type [`datetime64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html), you can compare datetimes like numerical objects.

Knowing this, you can define the ranges that you want your activity to be equal to "Sleep", "Work", etc...

Here's a snippet that shows how to set a slice of the column to be "Sleep". You just need to replicate this for "Work" and whatever other activities you want to include.

**edit:** added pytz to make tz-aware datetimes

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

sleep_start = pytz.utc.localize(datetime(2020, 1, 27, 0, 4, 59))    # 2020-01-27 00:04:59
sleep_end = pytz.utc.localize(datetime(2020, 1, 27, 7, 1, 43))      # 2020-01-27 07:01:43

is_sleeping = (df.index > sleep_start) & (df.index < sleep_end)

# initialize new column "Activity" to be empty
df['Activity'] = ''

# set the slice of the "Activity" column where `is_sleeping` is True to "Sleep"
df.loc[is_sleeping, 'Activity'] = 'Sleep'
```

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful! But I still have an issue, it says "TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects". I tried df.tz_localize(None), but it wasn't a helpful addition.. Do you know what should be done in this case?

Comment: Yes, I believe you have to use `pytz`. I believe it's already included with Python so you don't need to install anything else. See my edit above and give that a shot @Roxana